# linking Office 365 and ADFS on Azure

Tags: azure, microsoft-office-365, adfs

i am trying to link my ADFS to Office 365 in order to set up Single Sign On for Office 365. I am going over this [blog post](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj631606.aspx). at Step 5, i am supposed to run Powershell commands so i can connect the ADFS to Office 365.

```
Set-MsolAdfscontext -Computer <AD FS server FQDN>
Convert-MsolDomainToFederated -DomainName <domain name>
```

i am unable to determine the FQDN for the ADFS server. i searched around a lot on the web, but was not able to locate the solution. i am just getting started with all configuration of ADFS and Office 365, but was not able to find out a solution. any answers?

Answer (score 1):

I recently setup AD FS for Office 365. I would recommend you to use the following technet blog:

[Install ADFS for Office 365 - Part 3](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rmilne/2017/05/14/how-to-install-ad-fs-2016-for-office-365-part-3/)

Kindly note that this is Part 3 and there are two other parts if you need assistance with the initial configuration.

As you might see in the document,

```
Set-MsolAdfscontext -Computer <AD FS server FQDN>
```

is the adfs server name that you might have given the server while you setup the adfs role (example - adfs.companyname.com)

Then with the following PowerShell command,

```
Convert-MsolDomainToFederated -DomainName <domain name>
```

You would be able to convert your Office 365 domain from a Managed Domain to Federated. (The default domain name given in Office 365 is generally companyname.onmicrosoft.com however, you can verify your company domain and enter the same here as the domain name.)

Answer (score 0):

The FQDN is the one you entered while setting up ADFS. Normally something like sts.example.com, federation.example.com, login.example.com

Comment: ok. and the domain name will be the one i registered with Office 365, right?

Comment: does not have to be. You already used it in the ADFS config... just look at your ADFS config

Comment: DNS Name: abcdsso.cloudapp.net
User: myuser
Password: password

Domain Controller
Root Domain Name: abcd.com
NetBIOS Name: ABCD

so FQDN would be: abcdsso.cloudapp.net

Comment: Michel, that answer is incorrect. Please see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj205461.aspx. The value entered for context is not the federation service hostname.

Answer (score 0):

Please see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj205461.aspx. This explains exactly how to federated Adfs with o365.

Comment: i could not understand what FQDN to put. whenever i try to enter the powershell command, it rejects my credentials. will the FQDN be the federation service display name? or will it be server name, as seen in the ADFS section in Server Manager on Azure?